# Devise sign up form on the home page as well

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I want the ability to display the sign_up form on the homepage of my app `home#index` as well as the default page Devise creates.

Devise has the instruction to do this for the sign_in page but how can I do it with sign_up?
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app

Thanks!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Paste this in your `home#index` view code

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "links" %>
```

and

```
 def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource_class 
     User 
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
```

in your `Application Helper` file.
You are good to go.

Comment: For the last line I had to use `<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>`, otherwise all good!

Comment: Also add `def resource_class User end` to the `ApplicationHelper`

Comment: I recommend manually setting the ids of the form and fields to be syntactically correct when you have identical forms on the same page (ie. when the user is on the sign in page).

Comment: If there is server_side validation that fails, how do we know when page to render next?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the explanation from Devise [How To: Display a custom sign_in form anywhere in your app](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app)

> Another example with form_for and posting to user_session_path:

```
<%= form_for(:user, :url => session_path(:user)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
  <%= f.label :remember_me %>
  <%= f.submit 'Sign in' %>
  <%= link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path(:user) %>
<% end %>
```

I placed it in my new view