# Devise - custom views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Rather than using the Devise views created through

```
rails g devise:views
```

Is it possible to use devise with existing sign up/in pages?

I know you can create the devise controllers and views but what is the process for creating your own?

I have read something about overriding controllers so it seems possible?

Comment: just edit the file that got generated by rails g devise:views

Comment: Or call the devise controllers.

Comment: @icemelt I dont want to edit the devise views as they are in the wrong place and I already have a significantly different signup/sign in page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you want to login not from default devise views right?

put this in your controller

```
helper_method :resource_name, :resource, :devise_mapping

  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
```

and make sure ur login form is like this

```
<%= form_for(:user, :url => session_path(:user)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
  <%= f.label :remember_me %>
  <%= f.submit 'Sign in' %>
  <%= link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path(:user) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need. In order to make my own signin , forgotten password etc pages is the approach the same?

Comment: pretty much same, more is here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381817/devise-sign-up-form-on-the-home-page-as-well